# Unsupported protocol when running jar file

Tags: java, resources, protocols

I recently made a minesweeper game and i'm trying to add sound to it. At the moment I have the following code:

```
try {
        AudioClip explosion = new AudioClip(Main.class.getResource("explosion.mp3").toString());
        explosion.play();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Alert error = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            error.setContentText(e.getLocalizedMessage() + e.toString());
            error.showAndWait();
        }
```

When I run the program from Eclipse it works as intended. However if I export it to a runnable .jar I get an exception. "Unsupported protocol "rsrc"java.land.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported protocol "rsrc" ".

I've tried a range of different ways that I've seen on online to include a audio file but I can only ever get it to work in Eclipse and never when in a jar.